# Change html lang attribute when locale changes

Tags: html, symfony, internationalization, symfony-2.1, lang

I have a multilangual website running with PHP/Symfony2.

I would like to change the html lang attribute when the user switches language (= switching locale).

What is the best way to achieve this?

PS: my ultimate goal is to be able to switch font for different languages (chinese looks just too bad with the font I chose for english). I am thinking of using the CSS :lang() pseudo selector: `html:lang(zh)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Asuming you are using html5 and twig as template engine:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="{{ app.request.locale }}">

...
```

Comment: That was so obvious and yet I didn't think of it.. Thanks! Now I'll work on how to change the font based on the language used.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of storing locales is language code underscore country code, e.g. en_GB.

> The term locale refers roughly to the user's language and country. It
>   can be any string that your application uses to manage translations
>   and other format differences (e.g. currency format). The ISO 639-1
>   language code, an underscore (_), then the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country
>   code (e.g. fr_FR for French/France) is recommended.
>   http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html

Therefore, a safe way of using the locale in the lang attribute would be:

```
<html lang="{{ app.request.locale|split('_')[0] }}">
```

This works with both an **en_GB** locale and an **en** locale.

Comment: lang attribute accepts full locale, just like elements in HTTP Accept-Language header

Comment: But they must be separated with a dash rather than an underscore, e.g. en-cockney.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1.1

Comment: ah true. But I'd leave the country code when it's provided: `| replace({'_', '-'})`

Comment: Correct syntax according to my twig is `{{ app.request.locale | replace({'_':  '-'}) }}`