# How to pass locale using FOSJsRoutingBundle

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, url-routing

I installed FOSJsRouting but my route need `_locale` parameter. How can I do that in JS ? Is there a way to get the locale in js ?

In twig, I can do `app.request.attributes.get('_locale')` but in JS, I don't find any documentation.

## AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'get',
    url : Routing.generate('get_credits', {'_locale': app.request.attributes.get('_locale'), 'amount' : amount, 'monthNumber' : month }),
    beforeSend : function(){
    console.log('loading');
    },
    success: function(data){
    },
    error : function(){
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I usually do is set the locale as a html-tag attribute

```
<html lang="{{ app.request.locale }}">
```

which results in

```
<html lang="EN">
```

This is also useful for SEO, and you can always get the locale in JS by calling

```
$('html').attr('lang');
```

Comment: Ok. But I need to get the locale (EN|FR|NL) in the url. So I can't use static value.

Comment: That locale isn't static. it's <html lang="{{ app.request.locale }}">. I thought it's intuitive, sorry

Comment: Be careful using {{ app.request.locale }} in your lang attribute. See this post for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30538515/2106834

Answer (score 0):

If your Js scripts is in twig, you can do something like that :

```
var mylocale= "{{ app.request.attributes.get('_locale') }}"; // or {{ app.request.locale }}

$.ajax({
    type : 'get',
    url : Routing.generate('get_credits', {'_locale': mylocale, 'amount' : amount, 'monthNumber' : month }),
    beforeSend : function(){
    console.log('loading');
    },
    success: function(data){
    },
    error : function(){
    }
});
```

Comment: This is completely not recommended, as it messes up assetic functionalities like yui compressing and adds an extra processing step which slows down the front end part significantly

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `master` version of FOSJsRoutingBundle which includes a [PR](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/pull/145) that makes the `_locale` parameter injected automatically.

Update your `composer.json` file with:

```
"friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "dev-master"
```

And run:

```
composer update friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle
```

I don't like using `master` versions of libraries, but that is the easiest solution for now.